# Software to produce graphics of triangulated surfaces

Tags: general-topology, 3d, math-software, visualization, triangulation

I would like to find a software that lets me create graphics of a surface with a triangulation on it. It doesn't need to be very fancy; I just need to explain to a bunch of high schoolers what a triangulation of a surface is, but without getting technical. Everything will be pretty graphical and intuitive.

**EDIT:**
I would prefer something that’s open source since I have a Linux machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[trimesh2](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/trimesh2/) includes a mesh viewer, with binaries for popular platforms.

[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net) is a complete modeling system.